# error with filtering using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a piece of python code which is mentioned below but did not return what I want. and a file like this example:

```
AAAS,ENST00000552161,1.70232E-30
AAAS,ENST00000548258,1.09222E-84
AAAS,ENST00000549450,1.3171E-108
AAAS,ENST00000209873,22.3297
AAAS,ENST00000546562,0.170807
AAAS,ENST00000394384,5.53609
AAAS,ENST00000547238,0.829774
AACS,ENST00000316543,0.49901
AACS,ENST00000261686,2.41428
```

I the 1st column has a lot of repeated items. I want to choose only one of those based on the 3rd column. like the following rows:

```
AAAS,ENST00000209873,22.3297
AACS,ENST00000261686,2.41428
```

this is the code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('data.csv', newline='') as f, open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    f_reader = csv.reader(f)
    out_writer = csv.writer(out)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f_reader:
        d[line[1]].append(line)
    for _,v in d.items():
        new_line = sorted(v, key=lambda i:float(i[2]), reverse=True)[0]
        out_writer.writerow(new_line)
```

do you know what the problem is?

Comment: I don't think `new_line` is a list of strings when you pass it to `writerow`

Comment: I removed both newline=' ' but still it gave me all repeates

Comment: no, I meant your variable in the last loop `new_line`

Comment: so what to do then?

Comment: put a `print(new_line)` above the `out_writer.writerow` and see if it's a list.  If it's not then that's your problem

Comment: Lists are 0-indexed but you're grouping them together by `line[1]` which is the second element.  You want to group them by `line[0]`

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect problem for pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=None)
df.groupby(0).max()
#                    1         2
#0                              
#AAAS  ENST00000552161  22.32970
#AACS  ENST00000316543   2.41428
```